# can we use core data to store a real estate property?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I need to know what should I use to store the property?
I'm still confused. Should I use SQLit or core data?
I will have a lot of data, user data and real estate data. It will also appear in the map.

Comment: Is this going to be an offline app? Because if it's online, why use sql / core data? Just fetch JSON arrays from the server.

Comment: no it will not be offline, i have asked a prof before, he said to me "If you want to store persistent data for annotations, the best approach would be to use SQLite or Core Data."my idea is like application it's name is zillow but with a Few things deferent, if you have an iphone you can download it and see what's i mean ^_^, i have no site to store any data on it, should i have one?, i'm stil student :/ and really thanks for your comment ^_^

Comment: I thought mostly about the data in your map, but I think it's the other way around as you describe it, showing the online map and the pois are in your database. Anyway, if you need help ask :)

Comment: Thank you, when you said "Is this going to be an offline app?"
does this mean that core data will not work with online app? :/

Comment: No, I thought that you were going to get the data from an online database and then insert them to the core data/sql -- but i see it's a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data contains sqlite as a storage facility. It's not an actual database, but rather a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database).

SQLite on the other hand is a database. Different methodology, can be used for small chunks of data (I use it extensively) efficiently and mostly to implement a pure RDBMS system (with primary/foreign key, unions, and stuff like this, SQL powered).

For Core Data, you use graph relationships (which means objects connected to other objects by references).

The outcome is the same, different programming though, depending on the complexity you want to have (or actually have designed) in your app, so lay down your plans to see which one suits you. For SQLite I recommend FMDB wrapper, since it's easier instead of doing 2 to 3 checks for every SQL statement.

Your app seems interesting, and since it's real estate based you might want to spice it up a little bit later with a small technology called "augmented reality" :)

Comment: now i understand what SQLite and core data are, but if my app contain a photo and if i'm using the core data i could use either binary storage , XML and SQLite,, and again should i have my own web server or apple give this to me?
Really THANKS (F)

Comment: Apple does not give servers. You will need a webserver for develop (distribute images and stuff apart from maps). For development use your mac and point your (development/debug) app locally.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is my final project :$, I hope I choose the right decision by deciding to use core data and really thank you very much ^_^. you helped me a lot ^_^

Comment: No problem, we are all in the same journey afterall :)